# Перенаправление запросов программы к другому серверу

Tags: windows, ip

Имеется программа, которая обращается к ip адресу `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.`
Нужно перенаправить все эти запросы на другой ip адрес `YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY` с помощью средств windows (Адрес `YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY`принадлежит виртуальному серверу)

"route add" не работает,
ip маршрутизация включена

Comment: Если вам необходимо пробросить определённые порты, то используйте порт форвардинг. Пример можно глянуть [здесь](http://winitpro.ru/index.php/2014/12/23/nastrojka-port-forvardinga-v-windows/).

Comment: Какая версия Windows? Что такое средства Windows - штатные средства из дистрибутива или любые программы которые можно поставить? Можно ли изменить адрес клиента? "Виртуальный сервер" на этой машине? Чем больше подробностей тем легче решить проблему. Если хост находится не в локальной подсети клиента то эту проблему должен решить роутер, а не комп самостоятельно.

Comment: ну и если все совсем непонятно, то всегда можно использовать решение из самого первого комента. Правда как я понимаю перенаправить с помощью portproxy можно только входящие запросы, но зато можно повесть на локальную сетевую любой дополнительный адрес (т.е. ххх.ххх.ххх.ххх/32 ), а правило прописать netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=ххх.ххх.ххх.ххх listenport=ххх connectaddress=ууу.ууу.ууу.ууу connectport=ххх